# jquery to read and compare a word as you type

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to implement a sort of word sensing feature . What I require is to have a plugin which will read and compare a word, as I type , with a predefined word , and on successfull matches , it will display a checkbox .

[image]

As in the image , once I type test and give a space , it will take the entire word **Test** and compare it with a predefined word say "Testimony" . Now, as I have given a space after Test , it won't match with the reference word and it will wait for the next word. Again , as a user presses spacebar , it will take the new word and start comparing .

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a more customizable option than jQuery's autocomplete, you can bind a [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event to the textbox you are typing in, check the keycode of the key that the user is pressing, and act accordingly. Something along the lines of this:

```
 $('#textarea').bind('keypress', function(e) {

  var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);

  if( key == '32') {
    alert("spacebar was pressed");

    var input = $("#textArea").val();
    // Put your comparison logic here 
  }
});
```

I remember there being some funkiness with how IE handles codes, but the above works at least with FF and Chrome.

Comment: The funkiness is solved by your use of `e.keyCode || e.charCode`.